# Defining a different route for python app

Tags: python, routes, flask

Here is my python code

```
    import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
def Fun():
    return 'Having Fun!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

On loading the `www.example.com/` it goes to the `hello` function and returns `Hello World!`
How to point a url like `www.example.com/Fun` to another function `Fun`

***Update(Working Code)***

Updated code but still not working

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
    return 'Hello World --  jay!'

@app.route('/fun')
def fun():
    return 'have func!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: The "@app.route('/fun')" line should be just before the "def fun()" declaration, not before the "def hello()".

Comment: ok thnks for dat ...i have one more question is it possible to point @app.route('/fun') to another function name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorator @app.route sets url for your controller. So this code should work:

```
@app.route('/fun')
def fun():
    return 'Having Fun!'
```

Comment: ok dat worked...thnks, but i have one more question.Is it possible to point @app.route('/fun') to another function name?

Comment: Just change the decorator to another function!

Comment: Yes, as mentioned before, just add it before another controller. It doesn't care about function and url naming but it's good practice to have url similar to controller name.